# Bash: Use the results of `find` as the parameters of a different bash function

Tags: bash

I have a short shell script that gets chicken information from the `chickens` directory.  These are the three .txt files I have:

**********~\Desktop\Chickens (or sub directory)**********

```
++++++++ yoke-o-ono.txt ++++++++
NAME: Yoke-o-ono
TYPE: Hen
COLOR: White

++++++++ zelda.txt ++++++++
NAME: Zelda
TYPE: Hen

++++++++ fido.txt ++++++++
NAME: Some Dog named Fido (WTF Fido?)
COLOR: Black
```

There are a number of optional properties, but the three I care about are name, type, and color. I want to print all the chickens to the console in this format: "**[***NAME***] [***TYPE***]-[***COLOR***]**" (printing blanks if a field does not exist).

```
formatEcho () {
      echo "[$1] [$2]-[$3]"
}

getChickens () {
  find ~/Desktop/Chickens -name "*.txt" |
  xargs grep -h -e "NAME" -e "TYPE" -e "COLOR" |
  sed -E 's/^[A-Z].*:(.*$)/\1/g' |
  sed -E 's/^[A-Z].*:(.*$)/\1/g' |
  sed -E 's/^[A-Z].*:(.*$)/\1/g'
}

formatEcho $(getChickens)
```

However, as expected, this only outputs a single chicken.

```
[Yoke-o-ono] [Hen]-[White]
```

I could use some help integrating formatEcho into the getChickens method so that each chicken is displayed:

```
[Yoke-o-ono] [Hen]-[White]
[Some dog named Fido (WTF Fido?)] []-[Black]
[Zelda] [Hen]-[]
```

e.g., use the results of `find` as the parameters of `formatEcho`.

**EDIT (Attempting Scott's Answer)**

```
bash-5.1$ sh script.sh 
script.sh: line 21: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name
awk: can't open file /Users/MYNAME/Desktop/Chickens/**/*.txt
 source line number 14
```

script.sh:

```
shopt -s globstar
awk '
function formatEcho(na, ty, col) {
                        print "[" na "] [" ty "]-[" col "]"
                }
    FNR==1      {
                  if (NR != 1) formatEcho(name, type, color)
                  name=""; type=""; color="";
                }
                { data = $0; sub($1 " ", "", data) }
$1=="NAME:"     { name = data }
$1=="TYPE:"     { type = data }
$1=="COLOR:"    { color = data }
END             { formatEcho(name, type, color) }
    ' ~/Desktop/Chickens/**/*.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for showing us what you tried, but your try is not very good.  (1) You don’t need the three `sed` commands. The first one will do all the work; the second and third will do nothing.  (2) `find` piped into `xargs` is not a good way to handle files.  (3) Do you need to search subdirectories? If not, there’s no reason to use `find` at all. Even if you *do* need to search subdirectories, if you’re using `bash`, you don’t really need to use `find`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) You say “as expected, this only outputs a single chicken.”  You’ve done a bad job of debugging.  Try your solution (4a) in a directory that has chickens with NAME (and other, optional attributes) only — no TYPE or COLOR.  (4b) on a chicken that has NAME and COLOR but no TYPE, or NAME and COLOR *and **then*** TYPE. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … What do you really want to know?  How to solve *this specific problem* with chickens?  How to process multiple files with one command?  How to extract data from text files?  How to use `find`?

Comment: Why is that a bad job debugging? Yes, I've tried it in multiple use cases -- Yes its not a technical chicken, its just the first 3 complete lines, which could be 2 names and a color. However, it was never expected to work in the first place. I KNEW I needed to bring formatEcho up so that it could be run once per file found -- That's the piece I didn't know how to do.

Comment: I think I've done a perfectly good job at explaining what I want. Even the title is sufficient : Use the results of `find` as the parameters of a bash function, in this case, formatEcho. No, I couldn't care less about chickens lol, this is just an easily reproducible example.

Comment: I used `find` because I wanted to search sub directories, and that's why I asked for an answer using find as well. I have since edited my post though to make this desire more clear. I appreciate your opinion, but I actually got this approach from a different stack exchange solution. The answerer in this case advocated this solution.

Comment: OK, I’ll repeat what I said in my first comment: Even if you *do* need to search subdirectories, if you’re using `bash`, you don’t really need to use `find`.  If my answer (``shopt -s globstar`` and `**`) doesn’t give you the information you need, then I still don’t know what you want to know.

Comment: globstar does not work for a variable number of nested sub-directories. I really do think I need to use find lol.

Comment: `globstar` works fine with a variable number of nested sub-directories. You need `bash` version >= 4.0.

Comment: Okay, I am updating bash with `brew install bash`. Maybe that will help.

Comment: @Cyrus No luck. Reinstalled bash and now 'shopt' isnt even recognized. Maybe its not on macOS?

Comment: I assume that you are not using bash at least version 4.0.

Comment: echo $BASH_VERSION
5.1.16(1)-release

Comment: If you use Scott's answer in a script show your shebang and how do you run the script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134588/discussion-between-jeremiahduane-and-cyrus).

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Ditto. And even if it's linked to `bash`, `bash` called as `sh` does not behave like fully-featured `bash`.

Comment: Thank you, you wonderful people. I didn't know that. That solved this issue, and I expect many, many others in the future.

Comment: Investigate what shebang is and how to use it. Instead of `bash thescript` (or `sh thescript`) you want to run `./thescript` and let the kernel use the interpreter specified in the shebang of `thescript`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in awk, *with **bash**:*

```
shopt -s globstar
awk '
function formatEcho(na, ty, col) {
                        print "[" na "] [" ty "]-[" col "]"
                }
    FNR==1      {
                  if (NR != 1) formatEcho(name, type, color)
                  name=""; type=""; color="";
                }
                { data = $0; sub($1 " ", "", data) }
$1=="NAME:"     { name = data }
$1=="TYPE:"     { type = data }
$1=="COLOR:"    { color = data }
END             { formatEcho(name, type, color) }
    ' ~/Desktop/Chickens/**/*.txt
```

The `data = $0; sub($1 " ", "", data)` statements
get the data to the right of the label. 
It’s not a perfect way of doing it,
but it will work for the data you showed in your question.

With the `globstar` shell option *in **bash**,*
`**` will do a subdirectory search.

---

Your question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash),
and you mention “bash” twice in the title and a few times in the comments. 
And ***I*** mention “bash” twice in my answer
and a few more times in comments. 
So I would think that it goes without saying that this must be run in bash. 
[A comment by Cyrus](https://superuser.com/questions/1708106/bash-blah-blah-blah-bash-function/1708134#comment2632223_1708106) suggests that
you must use bash at least version 4.0. 
But maybe that wasn’t enough.

So, **this must be run in bash.**

- If you’re running your script the clunky way,
  you must say `bash script.sh`. 
  If you say `sh script.sh`, you’re running the default shell (`/bin/sh`),
  which may be POSIX-compliant, but probably isn’t bash
  (it might be the Bourne shell) — see the comments for discussion.
- If you’re running it as an executable script
  (do `chmod +x` and then run it as `./script.sh`),
  you must begin the script with a “shebang” of

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ```

  or

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  ```

  This must be the first line of the script.

Comment: I think `awk` is insufficient in finding the correct directory. I use find because it allows me to look inside a directory for all such files. So no, this doesn't work. I want ALL CHICKENS underneath the ~/Chickens directory, including maybe chickens in ~/Chickens/FreeRange

Comment: globstar does not work for a variable number of nested sub-directories.

Comment: Yes it does (unless, perhaps, if you have a very very old debug version of bash).

Comment: I am on macOS Monterey, but what you have there does not pull up any chickens. If I remove the ** though, it does.

Comment: I just put them all in an untitled directory under chickens, and that worked. I put them in another folder though, then I have to do Chickens/\*\*/\*\*/*.txt